# Converting a Multimap value from an int to a string?

Tags: c++

I have a multimap declared as:

```
typedef multimap <int, std::string> MM;
```

I was having trouble doing it how I normally do with no luck so used this method I found online:

```
std::string IntToStr( int n )
  {
  std::stringstream  result;
  result << n;
  return result.str();
  }
```

Then I call it passing it the int value of my multi map:

```
std::string stringNumber = IntToStr((*i).first);
```

What I get back is a bit of memory location I think, and the int converted tagged onto the end of this like:

```
64D20D6017
```

Where 17 is the score. What am I doing wrong? All I wanted to do was convert the results into a string to be used later.

Comment: Are you sure the actual number in i->first _is_ 17?

Comment: Yes, If I was to say cout << (*i).first << endl; I would get "17"

Comment: [Works fine here](http://ideone.com/j96Mo), there must be something wrong in the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Try updating your question with a [small, self-contained compilable](http://www.sscce.org/) program that exhibits the issue you are experiencing

Comment: Thanks ildjarn, that little snippet made my examine more closely because that's exactly what I have. It was a double cout causing the problem.

Comment: @lupz : There is no such thing as `std::itoa` -- `itoa` has never been part of the C or C++ standards. C++11's `std::to_string` is the closest shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just incase anyone ever gets a similar output, this was due to accidentally adding 2 `cout` to the line:

```
cout << variable1 << cout << variable2;
```